# What is the use of Ember.Application initialize method?

Tags: ember.js

I was trying the routing example in emberjs and I read that App.Initialize initializes all the controllers and inject them to the router (from [Emberjs](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Application.html#method_initialize) ). That means if I don't call the initialize method on my Ember Application my controllers won't get initiated and my router using those instance of controllers won't work. Right?

Then why [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anshulguleria/Pk4k2/8/) is working when i comment the line
`App.inialize()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hum, the fiddle your are working on refer to an outdated api. Looking to the source, Application#initialize() is now done automatically for you: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-application/lib/system/application.js#L419

BTW, you are also relying on an old router version. For now I'd suggest you to update to the current master, and read http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/ to see how to define it now.

Comment: The method which I am using is given in the [Router api](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Router.html). The link which you have given shows different way of doing it. So which is the better approach or when to use which.

Comment: This router Api is clearly deprecated... Ember.Router is no more a subclass of StateManager... I'd suggest you to clone and build the latest ember.js master branch